# Survey for team I am no longer a part of

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, global-inbox

I've received a notification to participate in a survey for a private team that I have not been a part of for over a year.

[image: Notification]

Comment: First question: "On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate the quality of your life after your departure from this team?"

Comment: Actually it's a survey about SO Teams and has nothing to do with the team you left. I am part of 2 teams and I got 2 survey invitations. The first was "Team 1 user survey" and the second was "Team 2 user survey".

Comment: @double-beep I didn't get a survey for the one team I am actually a part of

Comment: @AshleyMedway there's a bug here when dealing with deactivated users on a team, addressing it now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic we used to determine if you were eligible for a survey took into account that you were a member of another team, but it was considering all teams you were ever part of and used the deactivated one for the title of the inbox message.

Sorry about that, a fix is rolling to prod to make sure it ignores teams that you were deactivated from - that'll be there as shortly!

Comment: I think this wasn't fixed, had the same notification on the 17th Dec

Comment: @AshleyMedway same notification or a reminder? Reminders work off previously sent notifications, no changes made there, but we can address that in the New Year...

Comment: Ah yes, that will be it. It was a reminder